# How to open the camera with in the ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, camera, imageview

I want to open the Camera in the image view and on save button click.it save it Simple.And stop the camera movement.

Strongly i want open camera inSide of image `view` or anythink ELSE IN THE XML

Comment: so... what did you try so far?

Comment: I did it but camera open separately as look in mobiles .
and show the captured image in ImageView
i want to open camera in the imageView
That,s it

Comment: what I mean... is that you need to post some code so far. SO is not to gift you free code samples, use google for that.

Comment: use `TextureView` or `SurfaceView`, not `ImageView`

Comment: camera1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.camera);
    camera1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
           CustomValue =1;
               Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
              
     startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
          }
      });
    
  }

Comment: AND 


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST && CustomValue == 2) {
          Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view2);
          imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}